Redirect lua command to a file
Redirecting vim output to a file has been answered many times. The simplest solution is
:redir > vim.output | set fileencoding | redir END

But I use a lua command and so it doesn't work
:redir > vim.output | lua print("I m so annoyed by vim!!") | redir END

What is the simplest way to save the output of a lua command.

Stop using the pipes...that's the cause of the issue.
Write:
:redir > vim.output

Then
:lua print("I m so annoyed by vim!!")

Then
:redir END

To make this process shorter, developing a custom function would be relevant.
